# Why can't I see all the columns in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am displaying a pandas df in **Jupyter lab 0.35.5** with,

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)`
```

but I cannot see the righthand columns, there is no scrollbar (see image). How can I get them to display?

TIA!

[image]

Comment: try `pd.options.display.max_columns = 500`.

Comment: Thanks. Same problem still.

Comment: See @tawab_shakeels 'to enable scrolling' comment. It worked for me even with default max_columns setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

pd.options.display.max_columns = None
display(data)
```

To enable scrolling :

```
You can try Cell -> Current Outputs -> Toggle Scrolling in the Jupyter UI to enable the scrolling for the output of one cell.
```